# I need to bring in list of integers as a condition in Drupal rules

Tags: drupal-rules

I am trying to build a Drupal rule. My config is that my product has a integer list and a user reference. I have entity has field with both my user reference and my integer list.

My field client which is a user reference is in, but my integer list is not. I am using a component to schedule it based of my starting period which is the integer returned from the list of integers.

I have spent some time working on this with several variations, but the field just isn't there.

I need that integer list because it is my start day to add the offset for the components scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

If your products "integer list" ***is not*** available, you can ***make*** it available, similar to what is explained in [my answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/242013/39516) to "[How to access commerce_product field of line-items using Rules to flag the Commerce Product?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/241916/39516)" ...

Here is a blueprint of what you need to do (to further improve your rule):

1. Create a Rules Component (apart from the one you already have related to your "...component to schedule..."), similar to the Rules Component of Step 1 in [my related answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/242013/39516), just an import of that Rules Component should be enough (to get started and further improve it as detailed below).
2. Execute that Rules Component inside your Rules Loop of the rule you already have.